# Min Font size accessibility ticket

Tags: html, css, accessibility

I have to solve an accessibility problem:- "Font sizes should be at least 11px in size in order to stay readable in the majority of font families. This
should be verified also when using dynamic units such as REM or percents."

there are so many occurrences of font size in code its impossible to change them one by one. Is there any way to change all of them(font size all over the site) at once?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Are you saying that your code has been flagged as having this accessibility problem? Please show us the relevant code if so and make sure you explain the problem in such a way that it creates a question.

Comment: i have edited the problem statement to improve understanding

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Set base font size. to improve readability.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Simply [use clamp() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp) from CSS.

You can use it like so:

`font-size: clamp(11px, 2.5vw, 2rem);` meaning a minimum of 11px, default value of 2.5vw and max size of 2rem.

Comment: What did you interpret the question to be?

Comment: That OP wants to set a minimum font size of 11px. What's wrong with this?